# Python OpenCV: How to remove background from images with some overlapping color?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to automatically remove the background from images using OpenCV. The code I use generally works well, but for some images with similar background color to the foreground (e.g. white images with gray shadows on gray background), the code also removes that section of the image.
For example, for this image:

[target image to be processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55nRS.jpg)

I get the following result:

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3axZQ.png)

This is the code I use ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526621/remove-background-from-image-python)):

```
  img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
  thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
  thresh = 255 - thresh

  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
  morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=0)

  contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
  sorted_contour = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

  contour = np.zeros_like(gray)
  cv2.drawContours(contour, [sorted_contour[0]], 0, 255, -1)
  if len(sorted_contour) > 1:
    cv2.drawContours(contour, [sorted_contour[1]], 0, 255, -1)

  blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(contour, (5,5), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
  mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255))

  result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
  result[:,:,3] = mask
```

Any idea on how to modify the code so that it includes the "holes" in the dress, or to "patch up" the mask automatically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adjusting the values of threshold